# How do you design a website to make the best use of ads?

Tags: user-interface

Is anyone aware of general UI design guidelines for increasing ad revenue from web ads? Obviously many SO users use adblock, and probably find this type of question reprehensible, but I believe that it is possible to integrate advertising (and other revenue streams) into sites so that they are visually appealing, on-target, and functional. However, this is only a belief ;).

Given the widespread use of advertising as a means of income, this seems like it must be an active area of research.

I believe that any web design that is intended to generate income should take this into account, since the web designer (read: a sizable portion of the SO user base) should be trying to get the biggest return on their time/skills.

(This question is a repost because there is *no*way* on SO to contest a 'closed question', and it only takes one person with enough rep to decide they don't like it.)

**Edit:** Just incase anyone goes looking, I deleted the initial question (which was closed) since it didn't make sense to pollute the search results.

Comment: I agree with you on the premature closing of your previous post.  It seemed a little hasty.

Comment: I still think this is not programming related, but I'm willing to give you the benefit of the doubt and not close this one too.

Comment: Also agreed - advertising is highly relevant to website developers because the revenue from them is one of the main things that keeps us in a job.

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: Mark this as a flag day!  Avoiding over moderation is good!  Let the up/down votes speak for the quality of the post.  Save your moderation features for stopping Internet arguments that have failed (eg., edit wars).  Thanks Greg.

Comment: @Greg you may want to go close the posts about favorite comics, jokes, good posture, and pretty much every post with the .*uservoice.* so sofaq and stackoverflow tags too, for starters :)

Comment: All those will get closed eventually, I'm not the SO history police :)

Comment: @Overmoderation, Grrr!  Let the votes speak for the posts.  Closing a post is for dealing with inappropriate behavior.  Please read the FAQs again if you don't understand this yet.  Considering that Jeff has a blog post that addresses this question should speak for the value of the question.

Comment: i've always appreciated sites that let me disable ads too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, [one of the people who created this site](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1) made a [post regarding this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000893.html) on his [blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/)

Comment: ah, interesting! The (few) posts I've read on Jeff's blog have been more MS-centric than appeals to me (I just don't use those platforms) so I don't read coding horror frequently.  This is a good place to have a link to that article!

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in seeing [what Google has to say](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=17954) about the placement of ads.